# Sorting Table data onclick <th>in Google-App script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to sort the data(asc or desc) in the table. For this one I want to sort the  Date of VL & Date/Time of Application whenever I click on each header. However, my current code is not doing anything everytime I click it. But when I tried it on a static data it's working.

Here's my code below:

```
    <? var data = SpreadsheetApp
        .openById('sheet ID')
        .getSheetByName("VL Request")
        .getDataRange()
        .getValues(); 
   var timeStamp = [0];      
   var rid = [1];     
   var ldap = [2];
   var aname = [7];
   var lob = [9];
   var dovl = [5];
   var rol = [6];
   var tlapprov = [12];
   var tlrem = [14];
   var stat = [13];
   var schedrem = [11];
   var tl = [3];
   var pocldap = [15];
   var omldap = [16];
   var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();
  ?>
     <table id="vllist" class="vllist2">

       <tr>
           <th colspan=11>POC VIEW</th>    
       </tr> 
    <tr>
           <th colspan=11>Application for Date Range: <?= [formattedStart] ?> - <?= [formattedEnd] ?></th>    
       </tr>   
      <tr>
        <th style="display:none;">Request ID</th>   
        <th>LDAP</th>
        <th>Agent Name</th>
        <th>Lane</th>  
        <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Date of VL</th>
        <th>Reason of Leave</th>
        <th>POC Approval</th>
        <th>POC Remarks</th>
        <th>Scheduler's Approval</th>
        <th>Scheduler's Remarks</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(10)">Date/Time of Application</th>
      </tr>

     <? for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
            <tr> 
            <? if ((data[i][tlapprov] === "Pending") && ((data[i][pocldap] === userName) || (data[i][omldap] === userName)) && (data[i][dovl] >= startDate) && (data[i][dovl] <= endDate)) { ?>

            <?
            var vldate = data[i][dovl];
            var formattedDateVL = (vldate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + vldate.getDate() + '/' + vldate.getYear();
            ?>

              <td class="hide">
                <?= data[i][rid] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?= data[i][ldap] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?= data[i][aname] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?= data[i][lob] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?= [formattedDateVL] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?= data[i][rol] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?= data[i][tlapprov] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?= data[i][tlrem] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?= data[i][stat] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?= data[i][schedrem] ?>
                </td>
                <td class="lefttext">
                <?= data[i][timeStamp] ?>
                </td>

                <? } ?>
            </tr>
            <? } ?>

    </table> 

<script>
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("vllist");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";

  while (switching) {

    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;

    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {

      shouldSwitch = false;

      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];

      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {

          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {

          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {

      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;

      switchcount ++;
    } else {

      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like server side and client side code all mixed together. That's not going to work.  I'd recommend you try some of the quick start tutorials in order to learn some basics. Try going [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and do some reading.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is call the DATA into the table as normal... Then use JS to sort the records in the HTML table.

I think what you were trying to do is sort the data alphabetically first then display the data into the table . So rather put the data as is into the table, then use a sort Table function ..

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;      
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Click the headers to sort the table.</strong></p>
<p>The first time you click, the sorting direction is ascending (A to Z).</p>
<p>Click again, and the sorting direction will be descending (Z to A):</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
   <!--When a header is clicked, run the sortTable function, with a parameter, 0 for sorting by names, 1 for sorting by country:-->  
    <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Name</th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually that's the script I am using but it's not working if the data is coming from the spreadsheet.

Comment: You see the problem is that PHP is server side an js is client side . Mixing the two the JS is trying to sort something that does not exist in the client side yet .... The solution to would be to put the data into JSON using
 $json_data = json_encode($data); then use Javascript to render the table from JSON using         var Data = JSON.parse('<? print_r($json_data) ; ?>');  then apply the sort Script

Comment: instead of putting php values  directly into the table like               
   <td>
                <?= data[i][schedrem] ?>
                </td>

use  

document.getElementById('td1').innerHTML = Data[0][schedrem] from the Javascript json var

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution for being able to sort in a spreadsheet by clicking on check boxes above the the header row.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1') {
    if(e.range.rowStart==1 && e.range.columnStart<=sh.getLastColumn()) {
      sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).sort({column:e.range.columnStart,asc:(e.value=="TRUE")?true:false});
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what the Spreadsheet Might look like:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I understand it right. So if I click on a header in the html table I will just call the function and the actual spreadsheet will be sorted?

Comment: In this situation.  If you click on the checkbox above the header then that will issue an onEdit trigger which will call the onEdit(e) function and perform the operations within the function which will sort the table.

Comment: Doing it with a HTML is a little more complicated but achievable.

Comment: I am thinking if it's possible that the data in spreadsheet will not be moved but only sorted in the HTML table just for viewing?

Comment: Well it's actually pretty hard to tell what you want because you have server side and client side code all mixed together.

Comment: I was just providing a simple alternative to some one that appears to be new to Google Apps Scripting.

Comment: You can do all of your sorting client side if you wish with JavaScript only.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Best Practices for UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices) with Apps Script, you should [load your data asynchronously](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates).

To show you how to do this + to create a proper sorting function for you, I have created the following sample Sheet:

[image: Sample Sheet]

## Code.gs

```
function createSidebarWithHTML() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function getInitialData() {
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  result.shift(); //Removes header row from results
  //Returns an array of arrays [rows, rows, ...] where rows = [column, column, column, ...]
  return result;
}
```

## Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id='mytable'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan=4>POC VIEW</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan=4>Sample data!</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th onclick=sort(0)>Header 1</th>
          <th onclick=sort(1)>Header 2</th>
          <th onclick=sort(2)>Header 3</th>
          <th onclick=sort(3)>Header 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
    var loadedData = null;
    
    function loadTable(data) {
      loadedData = data; //For caching of the received data.
      var tablebody = document.querySelector('#mytable > tbody');
      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j=0; j<data[i].length; j++) {
          var newCell = document.createElement("td");
          var cellContent = document.createTextNode(data[i][j]);
          newCell.appendChild(cellContent);
          newRow.appendChild(newCell);
        }
        tablebody.appendChild(newRow);
      }
    }
    
    function sort(row) {
      var sortedData = loadedData;
      //Sort data based on row Number
      sortedData.sort(function(a,b) {
       return a[row]-b[row];
      });
      
      var tablebody = document.querySelector('#mytable > tbody');
      tablebody.innerHTML = ''; //Clear table body
      
      for (var i=0; i<sortedData.length; i++) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j=0; j<sortedData[i].length; j++) {
          var newCell = document.createElement("td");
          var cellContent = document.createTextNode(sortedData[i][j]);
          newCell.appendChild(cellContent);
          newRow.appendChild(newCell);
        }
        tablebody.appendChild(newRow);
      }
    }
    
    //initialize data
    function initialize() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadTable).getInitialData();
    }
    
    initialize();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```